# Простое распараллеливание Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте. Дабы не копать необьятную тему распараллеливания (я новичек, пытаться понять и попробовать всё будет очень долго), подскажите мне более конкретный метод. (видел как минимум три модуля threading, subprocess и  multiprocessing)

Задача состоит в том, чтоб после прибытия листа информации, каждый из его элементов обрабатывался в новом потоке, после чего закрывался. Без обмена информацией между потоками и в любом порядке. Подскажите, каким модулем проще и быстрее будет подобное реализовать?

Comment: Используйте threading

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.)
К сожалению как раз его я использовать и не хотел. Например [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/149420/).
Высвечивается проблема исключительной медленности этого модуля, перед простым однопоточным вычислением.

Comment: @РусланРедькин: если у вас проблемы с медленностью какого-либо кода, то следует привести именно этот конкретный код, указать результаты измерения производительности, версии ПО, используемое железо. Желаемый результат (насколько ускорить). Бессмысленно производительность обсуждать без конкретного кода (практически все вопросы, которые я  видел о "медленности потоков", в итоге были ошибками в коде авторов).

Comment: что значит *"после чего закрывался"*? Откуда это требование? Что вы хотите этим достичь?¶ Что ваша функция делает  с каждым элементом списка? (ввод/вывод? вычисления в Си расширениях? Запуск процессов?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess` из другой темы, он используется для вызова исполняемых файлов, или системных утилит. Затраты на запуск потока(`threading`), тем более процесса (`multiprocessing`) существенны, поэтому стандартная практика состоит в запуске N потоков или процессов, приходящий объект разделяется на части, запихиваемые в очередь, а каждый поток/процесс выбирает кусочки из этой очереди и обрабатывает. Потоки чуть проще, но из-за известных особенностей Питона (GIL) не всегда дают выигрыш в скорости, зависит от того, что там в обработке происходит. Причем специально у потоков/процессов сделан одинаковый интерфейс, так что легко заменить и проверить, что лучше.